# why we use NavHostFragment in name attribute of FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

We already know that we should use FragmentContainerView instead of FrameLayout

In this layout we define name attribute like below

```
   <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        ...   
        />
```

What is the purpose of defining this name? What it does under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

The `android:name attribute` used to add a default `Fragment` in the container.

It

- Creates a new instance of the Fragment
- Calls Fragment.onInflate(Context, AttributeSet, Bundle)
- Executes a FragmentTransaction to add the Fragment to the appropriate FragmentManager

For more insight on this head to: [Official Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView)

Comment: so NavHostFragment is special fragment defined in navigation package?

Comment: Not a special fragment, it is already mapping to your home fragment, you can change the fragment too. You will get a clear idea when you will write code or show the default code.